# Error with file IO in c++. terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what(): basic_string::resize

Tags: c++, file-io

i am trying to take some information from a file and then input it into three seperate arrays. the information is in the following format:
teanmane, probability1, probability2
Now it gets the information from the file an inputs into to three seperate strings but then it gives the above error and the dumps the core and exits. I connot see why.
following is the code.

```
string teamname[8];
double p1[8];
double p2[8];

        void input()
{
  ifstream file;
  char fileName[20];
  cin>>fileName;
    int arrindex=0;
  file.open(fileName);
  while(!file.eof())
    {
      int len;
      string line;
      string name;
      string buffer;
      string buffer2;
      stringstream temp;
      stringstream temp2;
      stringstream temp3;
      double probTg;
      double probFg;
      getline(file, line);
    cout<<line<<endl;      
    temp<<line;
      temp>>name;
      len=name.length();
      name.resize((len-1));
      name[len]='\0';
      temp>>buffer;
      buffer.resize(4);
      temp2<<buffer;
      temp2>>probTg;

      temp>>buffer2;
      buffer2.resize(4);
      temp3<<buffer2;
      temp3>>probFg;
    if(arrindex<8)
{
      teamname[arrindex]=name;
        cout<<teamname[arrindex];
        p1[arrindex]=probTg;
        cout<<p1[arrindex];
        p2[arrindex]=probFg;
        cout<<p2[arrindex];     
        arrindex++;
}
    }
file.close();
}
```

Comment: std::string's are not null-terminated char arrays.  Stop treating them like they are:
`name.resize((len-1));
      name[len]='\0';`
It makes no sense sticking nulls at the end of a std::string (and to top it all off, your index is out of bounds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are mixing stl idioms with c idoms.

The code below replaces your line parsing with scanf. I think it's much clearer than the same code done with << and >> operators.

```
string teamname[8];
double p1[8];
double p2[8];

void input()
{
   ifstream file(filename);
   if (file.bad()) return 1;

   int ix = 0;
   while (ix < 8) {
      if (file.eof())
         break;

      string line;
      getline(file, line);

      char * team;
      double d1, d2;
      int fields = sscanf(line.c_str(), "%a[a-zA-Z], %lf, %lf", &team, &p1[ix], &p2[ix]);
      if (fields >= 1) {
         teamname[ix] = team;
         free(team);
      }
      ++ix;
   }

   file.close();

   for (ix = 0; ix < 8; ++ix) {
       printf("%s %f %f\n", teamname[ix].c_str(), p1[ix], p2[ix]);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be problem to me. You just `resize` the string and putting something out resized size. In-fact two more than allocated size.

If allocation is `20`, then the statement below trying to put in `22`th memory location.

```
name.resize((len-1));
name[len]='\0';
```